# Выдает ошибку когда перехожу в панель администратора не могу понять в чем проблема буквально пару часов назад все работало

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**Код ошибки:**

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6071
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/stylesheets/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/stylesheets/mueller/grid/output.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
----------------------------------------
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 61280)
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:03] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bodja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Bodja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Bodja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Bodja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Bodja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Bodja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
----------------------------------------
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5809
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6071
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Jun/2021 01:42:11] "GET /static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

> requirements.txt asgiref==3.3.1 Django==3.1.7 django-autoslug==1.9.8
> django-cleanup==5.1.0 django-grappelli==2.15.1 Pillow==8.1.2
> pytz==2021.1 sqlparse==0.4.1

Python 3.9.5

Comment: Судя по логу проблема в том что не может найти статику, в частности grappelli. Сервер везде выдает 404 на загрузку статики. Возможно вы меняли настройки статики в settings.py или вообще удалили каталог со статикой (static). Или перевели сервер из режим DEBUG в False. Вообще сайт открывается (не входя в админку)?

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей, ошибка может выходить при разных случаях.

Answer (score 0):

Может вы поменяли какие-то настройки в settings.py или удалил какие-то файлы или каталоги вашего проекта?

[возможно поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562067)